# Hashing implementation on a list of size 1K in C

Tags: c, string, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I am a novice to C and I have a requirement where I need to do fast lookup on the basis of "e-mail id OR ipv4/6-address "

My struture should look like

```
{
  enum_usr_type ;/*(which can be either e-mail type or ip-address type)*/

  char_id_data ; /*(which can be either a email-id string OR ipv4/6 ip-address string) */
}
```

The size of complete database is expected to be 1K.

Can anyone suggest any pointers to how I should go about doing it(perhaps hash table , but I am not familiar).

Comment: Linear search through a contiguous array.

Comment: Yes, a hash table is a good solution in this case. Do you have any specific requirements/questions?

Comment: @KerrekSB Indeed, 1000 entries is not a lot of data.

Comment: 1K? Don't even start thinking about "fast", go with "simple". It is just not worth it.

Comment: There are timing constraints as a lot of heavy calculations are involved after we have find out the a particular email id OR ip -address is not in our list and I need to minimize the time needed to search in this list. How to calculate the hash key , hash function ,how to add a node in the hash table is what I was looking to get help for.

Comment: If the type is IP address, is it still a string? As in a sequence of characters like `"192.168.1.2"`, not four bytes like `192, 168, 1, 2`? If so, just ignore the difference and use any string hashing function.

Answer (score 0):

**POSIX hash table management**

```
man hsearch
```

**Libhash**

ftp://ftp.ugh.net.au/pub/unix/libhash/

Libhash is a small hash library written in C

Once installed

```
man libhash
```

I personally prefer libhash, it's very small and you can embedded in your code quite easily, also it's very easy to use:

```
hash h;

/* in your case number_of_buckets = 2053, 1k*2 = 2048, the next prime number is 2053. */
hash_initialise(&h, 2053U, NULL, NULL, NULL, free, free)

/* insert */
hash_insert(&h, key, value);

/* retrieve */
hash_retrieve(&h, key, &ptr);

/* dispose hash table */
hash_deinitialise(&h);
```

again

```
man libhash
```

Comment: i was looking around and at some places DJB2 algo is recommeneded for string hash ... can you tell me how to calculate bucket size for DJB2

Comment: @HimanshuGupta It depends the nature of the hash function you're using, for instance, some behave better if it's prime number of buckets, for others it might not matter that much, in this case with libhash it's better if it's a prime number. In your case, JB2 it's just the hash function (someone correct me if I'm wrong) you still need to handle collisions and a lot more to end up with what you are looking for.

as n.m said, with 1Kb of data don't start to think about fast, go with simple.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta if you want to implement your own hash table, don't do it, you'll be reinventing the wheel.